# Adobe Flash Player installation progress always stopps at 12%

Tags: flash-player, adobe-flash

I can download the file flash player 11.1.102.55.
http://aihdownload.adobe.com/bin/install_flashplayer11x32_mssd_aih.exe

I use Windows 7.
Java Scirpt is activated.
No Virus scanner is installed.
I have a 32 Bit device.

But in Firefox and Opera it stop retrieving data at 12%.

Can somebody help me?

More details necessary?

Comment: JavaScript should not have anything to do with the installation of the Flash plugin. When you run the installer, it should install outside of the browser, using an Adobe AIR interface.

Comment: Does the *download* of a file in the browser stop, or the *installation* progress when installing it? Or maybe the download of additional components within the installer?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the offline installer and using that? I had a similar problem.

Comment: I upgraded Adobe AIR from 1.5 to 3.x. but nothing changed.

Comment: @Daniel oh sorry, the installation progress stopped.

Comment: @kame You do not need to install Adobe AIR prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their online installer is terribly buggy. Try the direct download links:

- [ActiveX](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player_ax.exe)
- [NPAPI](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player.exe)